# How does Emacs ORG mode work?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, org-mode

I am not too familiar with emacs lisp. Before I dig in and try learning it blind, I was hoping someone could give me a high level overview of how Emacs org mode work (or even emacs itself).

What I don't understand is how is it keeping track of things like headers, todos etc. How does it markup the text? Does it use something like html and when you make a header like * HEADER. It wraps it in some tag to know to change it's color? Or is it simply doing syntax highlighting like it would when coding. Just instead of when it sees a def when it sees a * and some text it changes the color?

Also the commands for movement, changing heading sizes, deadlines.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJTwQvgfgMM

Comment: To answer your second question. It uses some grammar rules to highlight the text. It doesn't use an "invisible" markup behind the stages. The keybindings for `org-mode` are rather vast. They are also context-sensitive (they may not do the same thing, depending on where in the document you are). My advise is to start small and then try to discover things as soon as you are facing a need to do something. Learning all at once would be a very difficult undertaking.

Answer (score 1):

1. How does org mode keep track of things?

   Just imagine that each time that you call agenda, org-mode "compiles"
   all your org files, just like `gcc` would compile your source tree.
2. The highlighting 
   This is done in the same way as for source code highlighting,
   i.e with regexps.
3. The commands you can learn either from http://orgmode.org/
   or from `info org`.
   Also I've found http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html very useful
   to get a feel of a full workflow with org-mode.